# How do I enter Python code in PDB without having it interpreted as a command?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, pdb

Sometimes I want to type Python code in PDB, if that code happens to start with a PDB command, you'll get an error

```
(Pdb) list()
*** Error in argument: '()'
```

How do I avoid this? It's sometimes surprising because I haven't memorized all 40-ish commands and their short forms and my code will just error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prefix them with `!`:

```
(Pdb) !list()
[]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-!